# Calling an Ethereum contract function from PHP

Tags: contract-invocation, php

How can I call a contract function from PHP and print the return? Is there any good PHP libraries for that? thanks.

Comment: The 'duplicates' links don't have methods to work with contracts.

Comment: Now they have. It's work in progress, but continuously improving.
Have a look here http://ethereum-php.org/dev/dc/dc6/class_ethereum_1_1_smart_contract.html

The source is [Ethereum-PHP](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php)